# Image of set difference preserved only by surjectivity? Injectivity is missing.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f : X \to Y$ be surjective and $U \subset Y$, then $f(X - f^{-1}(U)) = Y - U$.

I thought that the general results was only inclusions and equality if injective $$Y - U \subset f(X - f^{-1}(U)).$$

In any case what I wrote does not seem to require infectivity. So if $$f(x) \in f[ X - f^{-1}(U)] \iff x \in X - f^{-1}(U) \iff x \not\in f^{-1}(U) \iff f(x) \not\in f(f^{-1}U) \iff f(x) \in f(X) - U = Y - U$$

What on earth am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**Proposition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Let $f:X\to Y$. For each $B\in \mathscr{P}(Y)$, $f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)\subseteq B$.

*Proof.* Let $B\in\mathscr{P}(Y)$ be arbitrary. \begin{align}
f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)&=\left\{y\in Y:(\exists x\in f^{-1}(B))[f(x)=y]\right\}\\
&=\left\{y\in Y:(\exists x\in \{z\in X:f(z)\in B\})[f(x)=y]\right\}\\
&=\left\{y\in Y:(\exists x\in X)[f(x)=y\,\wedge\, f(x)\in B]\right\}\\
&\subseteq B.
\end{align}

**Remark.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Let $f:X\to Y$. If $f$ is surjective (i.e. onto), then for each $B\in \mathscr{P}(Y)$, $f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)=B$.

**Proposition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Let $f:X\to Y$. For each $A\in\mathscr{P}(X)$, $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$.

*Proof.* Let $A\in\mathscr{P}(X)$ be arbitrary.
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(f(A))&=\{z\in X:f(z)\in f(A)\}\\
&=\{z\in X:f(z)\in\{y\in Y:(\exists x\in A)[f(x)=y]\}\}\\
&=\{z\in X:(\exists x\in A)[f(x)=f(z)]\}.
\end{align}
$$A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A)).$$

**Remark.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Let $f:X\to Y$. If $f$ is injective (i.e. one-to-one), then for each $A\in\mathscr{P}(X)$, $A= f^{-1}(f(A))$.

**Proposition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Let $f:X\to Y$. For each $B\in\mathscr{P}(Y)$, $f^{-1}(Y\setminus B)=X\setminus f^{-1}(B)$.

*Proof.* Let $B\in\mathscr{P}(Y)$ be arbitrary.
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(Y\setminus B)&=\{z\in X:f(z)\in (Y\setminus B)\}\\
&=\{z\in X:f(z)\in \{y\in Y:y\notin B\}\}\\
&=\{z\in X:f(z)\notin B\}\\
&=\{z\in X:z\notin f^{-1}(B)\}\\
&=X\setminus f^{-1}(B).
\end{align}

> Furthermore, if $f$ is surjective $(\ast)$, then
>   \begin{align}
> f^{-1}(Y\setminus B)&=X\setminus f^{-1}(B)\\
> Y\setminus B\overset{(\ast)}{=}f\left(f^{-1}(Y\setminus B)\right)&=f\left(X\setminus f^{-1}(B)\right).
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, so I'll simply prove the following :

> If $X,Y$ are set and $f : X \to Y$ a surjective map of set, then for any $U \subset Y$ we have $Y - U \subset f(X - f^{-1}(U))$.

**Proof** : let $ y \in Y - U$. By surjectivity, there is some $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. By construction $x \in X - f^{-1}(U)$, so $Y - U \subset f(X - f^{-1}(U))$.

Notice that surjectivity is important : taking $U = \emptyset$ gives us $Y \subset f(X)$, i.e $f$ is surjective. So we showed that $f$ is surjective if and only if for every $ U \subset Y$,  $Y - U \subset f(X - f^{-1}(U))$.

Let's do the other direction :

> If $X,Y$ are set and $f : X \to Y$ a map of set, then for any $U \subset Y$ we have $f(X - f^{-1}(U)) \subset Y - U$.

**Proof** : This is tautological. Let $x \in X - f^{-1}(U)$. By definition $f(x) \in Y - U$. So $f(X - f^{-1}(U)) \subset Y - U$.

Nothing (surjectivity, injectivity) about $f$ is assumed for this direction.

Comment: Let $X_0, X_1 \subset X$, then we always have the inclusion $f(X) - f(X_0) \subset f(X - X_0)$. We have equality if and only if $f$ is injective. My condition seems to be fulfilled with subjectivity alone as I have proven myself. But the general result requires injectivity.

Comment: I don't understand again sorry. Do you say my answer is wrong ? Or it's not what you wanted to prove ?

Comment: I am not trying to prove anything. I am asking why the standard results is not applying here. I already wrote the proof myself.

Comment: Maybe you should use some quantificators ? I didn't use that for any $X_0,X_1$ ... but only for the $X_1$ on the form $f^{-1}(U)$ and $X_0 = X$.